# What is the name of this symbol ( ┐) and what does it mean

Tags: finance

Sorry bout the dumb question, it's just that I'm taking a mathematical finances class and the teacher started using this symbol today but I've never seem it before, was trying to google it but don't know its name and searching for the symbol itself yields 0 results.!

It's the $┐$ in the following equation.

$$A = R \frac{1 − (1 + i)^{− n}}{i} (1 + i) = R \,a_{\overline{n}|i}\, (1 + i)$$

There are also these other equations [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvmWJ.jpg)

Comment: A little more background would be nice...

Comment: Do you know what the letters mean? In particular, $a$ comes out of nowhere.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation) may be of some use?

Comment: @ZachGershkoff so, it seems to me it's the same as the upper case $A$, which is the "actual value" in annuity theory. $i$ is the interest rate, $R$ is the value of the periodical payment and $n$ is the number of periods.

Comment: @Ken Oh, ok, that's it. The symbol is "x-angle-y at z". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{\overline{n}|i}$ (read a-angle-n at i) is the present value of an annuity-immediate:
$$
a_{\overline{n}|i}=\frac{1-(1+i)^{-n}}{i}=\frac{1-v^n}{i}\qquad\text{with}\;v=\frac{1}{1+i}
$$